# Git Lab Set Content type in webhook

Tags: gitlab, travis-ci

I am trying to add a webhook to Travis CI, and the issue the content needs to be `x-www-form-urlencoded` but I don't see an option to set it in the webhook's config.  It gets set it to json and Travis is throwing a 422.

Is there something I need to enable in gitlab for this to work?  I am unable to modify Travis to accept json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hardcoded to json, you can't change it.